# Protractor removes element from the dom

Tags: angularjs, dom, testing, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm stucked in a test with protractor, because of a strange (and not so cool) behaviour of the template we are using.

On page load, the template has on overlay that is going to be hidden after 1 second in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(config){
    setTimeout(function(){
       $('.page-loading-overlay').addClass('loaded');
       $('.load_circle_wrapper').addClass('loaded');
    },1000);
});
```

*That feel terrible to me (don't want to comment about this)

Anyway my test get broken because of they run faster than a second and they throw this error:

```
UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (463, 625). Other element would receive the click: <div class="page-loading-overlay loaded">...</div>
```

Because obviously is the overlay to receive the click.

I found a workaround setting a timeout in the test, but this is will really slow down my suite and CI/CD process. And make the test code messy.

Here is the code:

```
it('should test something', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        // test code
    }, 1000);
});
```

I was wondering if there is any way to remove an element from the DOM in the `beforeEach` statement, to completely remove the overlay as I don't want to test it and I'm not worried if it broke.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What if you close/remove the overlay in the test first before you continue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`browser.executeScript`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript) to execute some code in he context of the browser:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  browser.executeScript("$('.page-loading-overlay').remove();");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, following @alecxe advice, I avoid to remove that element and simple add the classes in the beforeEach. I prefer to follow this approach because I would like to keep the tests as fast as possbile.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think removing a part of the DOM structure during testing is a good idea. Instead of using a timeout, explicitly wait for the element to be clickable:

```
var elm = element(by.id("myid"));
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(elm), 5000);
```